# Search throug server data does not work in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Trying to search trough extrnal api Weather servis.

Api is tested and works fine.

Problem: Enter value in search bar and main Search method from servis is not called. That is reason why request is not sent.

I follow tutorial from angular official documentation: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#search-by-name

And this not work.

Search Component:

```
export class SearchCityComponent implements OnInit {
  cities$: Observable<City[]>
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>()

  constructor(private weaterService: WeatherService) {}

  // Push a search term into the observable stream.
  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cities$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(300),

      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap((term: string) => this.weaterService.searchCities(term))
    )
  }
}
```

Service:

```
 /* GET cities whose name contains search term */
  searchCities(term: string): Observable<City[]> {
    if (!term.trim()) {
      return of([])
    }
    return this.http
      .get<City[]>(`${this.citiesUrl}/?query=${term}`, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`found cities matching "${term}"`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<City[]>("searchCities", []))
      )
  }
```

**When I enter in search input some value:**

In Search Comnponent in ngOnInit() last line of code is **Not** called search function from services?

```
 switchMap((term: string) => this.weaterService.searchCities(term))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An observable will be triggered only if it's needed, to tell to an Observable that you need it you have to subscribe to it :

```
    this.searchTerms.pipe(
      // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
      debounceTime(300),

      // ignore new term if same as previous term
      distinctUntilChanged(),

      // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
      switchMap((term: string) => this.weaterService.searchCities(term))
    ).subscribe()
```

Comment: Wehen I added subsctbe() I am getteing the error: http://prntscr.com/n1ih7n

Comment: I just make a new cities array which is not Observable and this works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot subscribe with `switchMap`!

As per the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/observables#subscribing):

> An Observable instance begins publishing values only when someone subscribes to it. You subscribe by calling the `subscribe()` method of the instance, passing an observer object to receive the notifications.

Comment: I am new to angular, can you give me more information about this answer? To  be able to undrestand.

Comment: I am using switchMap((term: string) => this.weaterService.searchCities(term))

Comment: maybe is problem cus that is in ngOnInit? That is called only once when component is called right?

Comment: Hi, switchMap((term: string) => this.weaterService.searchCities(term)).subscribe( data => this.data = data) its for example. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is alright. You just have to unwrap the `cities$` Observable in your Template using an `async` pipe. It's recommended to use the `async` pipe wherever possible. Just makes the code less verbose.

Doing something like this would help:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let city of cities$ | async">
    {{ city.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/movie-app-using-the-omdb-api?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.